# Space leaks with Haskell's cereal library?

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, unmarshalling

As a hobby project called '[beercan](https://github.com/rhymoid/hs-beercan)', I'm reverse-engineering the resource files of the Torchlight games. Using an okay-ish hex editor, I try to guess the structure of the files, and then I model my ideas, use [`cereal`](https://github.com/rhymoid/hs-beercan) to write `Get`ters (and later some `Put`ters), and try to `decode` every file in an application of the library.

I've just started on Torchlight's compiled layout files (`*.LAYOUT` in TL1, `*.LAYOUT.cmp` in TL2). The format turns out to be a little trickier than the dat files, but I think I figured out the [basic structure](https://github.com/rhymoid/hs-beercan/blob/master/src/Beercan/Data/LayoutTree2.hs), and [how they are encoded in the TL2 files](https://github.com/rhymoid/hs-beercan/blob/master/src/Beercan/Storage/CompiledLayoutFile.hs). so I'm trying to make a map of file versions, tag numbers, and guessed data types.

To do so, I wrote [an application](https://github.com/rhymoid/hs-beercan/blob/master/apps/IndexLayoutScheme.hs) that flattens the data structure, leaving only the guessed type of the values of the leaves, each annotated with the file version and the node and leaf tag numbers. I turn this into a map from the file version and tag numbers to a set of the guessed types. **For every file, I'd expect this Map to maybe take twice the file size in memory.** (Not sure, though.) Then, I merge these maps, and I print the map.

For some reason, even if I only take 20MB worth of files (100 files), memory usage increases linearly to about 200MB, then decreases to the final size of the resulting map, and then deflates rapidly as I print it.

I wouldn't expect this memory usage. Does anyone know how I could fix it? I've tried to force values after decoding them (using deepseq), I've tried adding bangs to data types, but this hasn't really helped. I've tried copying all bytestrings I keep in the file structure, which brought down the memory usage a bit, but it's still unacceptably high, especially when I want to analyze the entire dataset (200MB+ of original files).

---

-edit- I've pushed a (not very S)SCCE to demonstrate the performance issue, (accidentally) along with my profiling results.

1. Clone the repository.
2. `cabal configure`, with flags to enable profiling (is it normal to need `--enable-library-profiling --enable-executable-profiling --ghc-options="-rtsopts -prof"`?)
3. `cabal build`
4. `cd test`, and run `StressTest.sh`.

This script tries to load a regular TL2 layout file 100 times. On my machine, `top` says it takes about 500MB of memory, and the profiling results are consistent with my description above.

Comment: Could you please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? A piece of code that we could run, that'd demonstrate the memory problem, without the need to explore the whole application. Perhaps just a dummy parser that reads `/dev/zero` several times or something like that.

Comment: If it helps, I provided a stress test case which demonstrates the problem, but I wouldn't really know how to trim the problem without inventing my own file format :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally agree with @petrpudlak, <s>we would need actual code to make any meaningful comments to the question "why does my code use so much memory?" :)</s> (sorry, you did offer code), however, some of the patterns you describe are pretty typical in Haskell and some generic discussion is possible.

First of all, note that native Haskell types use a lot more memory than you might guess.  Take a look at the ghc memory footprint page at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Memory_Footprint.  Note that even a simple Char will take a full 16 bytes of memory!  Add to that pointers for linked list items in a String, and you will easily use more than an order of magnitude greater memory than you might have guessed.  If memory is important, you should use another data type, like Data.Text or Data.ByteString, which store Strings internally more like c would (as a block of bytes in memory, with 1-4 bytes per char, depending on encoding and what char is used).  If data other than Strings are the problem, you can use unboxed arrays for arbitrary data types.

Second of all, if possible, you can cut down memory usage by processing items in series (where the memory will be garbage collected right away).  Haskell laziness often does this for you automatically, for instance, try to run the following program

```
import Data.Char
main = interact $ map toUpper
```

As you type, the output will appear continuously (your OS, not Haskell, may buffer full lines, so you may need to hit 'enter' before seeing anything, but you will see output update for each 'enter').  Rather than loading the whole input into memory and then processing all at once, Char memory is being created and garbage collected Char by Char.

Of course this isn't always possible (ie- if you have to process the data in a very nonlocal way), but most of the time at least parts of the code can be refactored this way to cut down total memory usage.

---

Edit- Sorry, I just realized that you did post a link to the code, and you are using ByteString.....  So some of what I wrote isn't valid.  But I do still see boxed lists and unpacking of the ByteString, so I will leave the answer as it is.

Comment: By processing everything in series (by writing an `M.unionsWith` which sequences the accumulation of maps `IO`, and which is strict on the accumulator) solved the memory usage issue. I could cut down the usage to about 2MB. Thanks, I think I can improve it from here! :D

Answer (score 0):

The memory usage pattern sounds like your application is building up a lot of unnecessary thunks and then memory consumption starts going down when those thunks get evaluated. I only glanced at your code quickly but one simple change you could try is to replace all imports of `Data.Map` with `Data.Map.Strict`. This is especially important if you are doing a lot of updates on the values inside a Map without forcing evaluation in between.

Another things you should be aware of is that `replicateM` is quite inefficient with larger numbers in a strict monad (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20690878/572606)). I'm not sure what kinds of counts you are usually dealing with in your application, but it's good to keep in mind.

It might also help to use strict fields in simple container data types like your `LeafValue` type and compile with `-funbox-strict-fields` (and `-O2` of course).